# Creating a polygonal geofence

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding

Does anyone know how to create a polygonal geofence in Android? [I know that Android supports circular (i.e., lat/long + radius)](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) geofences, but I need more precise control over their boundaries.

Comment: Huh. I searched for an answer several times and I didn't ever come across that. I'll look into it today.

Comment: It was asked 5 days after your question is probably why ;o

Comment: (That worked, so add a link to that as the answer and you'll get the bounty :D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For concerns about **CPU & power consume**, I recommend to use the solution decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133568/891479).

1. Create a fake circular geo-fence around your Polygon
2. When a geofence alert is thrown for this circular geofence, evaluate if it is also inside your Polygon using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18486861/891479) provided by Karl.

Comment: Good idea! As far as I know they do that in video games as well to make collision detection more efficient. I never would've thought to use it in geofences. Thanks!